# Is there a way to automate service principal connections for ACR and AKS (in azure portal) from Azure Devops ? or can we acheive this with a pipeline?

Tags: terraform, azure-devops, azure, azure-kubernetes-service, acr

Here, I'm trying to create ACR and AKS (in azure portal) with terraform tasks in azure devops pipeline and right after creating these resources I'm trying to add "deploy into AKS" task in the same pipeline (or a different pipeline) and then after the build completes, all the resources should get destroyed in azure portal. **The main point is that this pipeline should work without any manual intervention(creating service connection everytime for ACR and AKS).**